# Please Explain what is difference between i=i++; and i++. Please look at code below and make me understand how it works in case of first condition?

Tags: operators, increment, post-increment

look at these two conditions in the code and output respectively:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=1;

   i=i++;  // first condition 
    i++; //2nd condition 

   cout << i << endl; //it will print 2 in second condition **but why print 1 in first condition?**
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i++ will increment i, but will *return* the original value.
So,

```
int i=0;
int x = i++; // x = 0, i = 1
```

if you wanted to return the *new* value, use ++i instead.

```
int i=0;
int x = ++i; // x=1, i=1
```

Comment: Hi @greg , please check question ,  i was storing result in same variable itself. in your case there is not doubt.

Answer (score 0):

the statement `i++` increases `i` **after** the statement is executed.
in contrast to `++i` which increases `i` **before** the statement is executed.
so the code

```
int i=1;
i=i++;
```

does:

1. (line 1) initialize variable `i` with value 1.
2. (line 2) insert the current value of `i` (1) to the variable `i` (it is not yet changed).
3. (line 2) increases `i` from 1 to 2.

the code

```
int i=1;
i++;
```

does:

1. (line 1) initialize variable `i` with value 1.
2. (line 2) increases `i` from 1 to 2.

The difference is more clear in those examples:

### example a

```
int i=1;
i=10+(i++);
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

does:

1. (line 1) initialize variable `i` with value 1.
2. (line 2) compute the result of 10 plus the current value of `i`(1) (result 11).
3. (line 2) insert result 11 of last computation to `i`.
4. (line 2) increases `i` from 11 to 12.
5. (line 3) print 12.

### example b

```
int i=1;
int j = i++
i=10+j;
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

does:

1. (line 1) initialize variable `i` with value 1.
2. (line 2) insert the current value of `i`(=1) to `j`.
3. (line 2) increases `i` from 1 to 2
4. (line 3) compute the result of 10 plus the current value of `j`(=1) (result 11).
5. (line 3) insert result 11 of last computation to `i`.
6. (line 3) print 11

### example c

```
int i=1;
int j = i++
i=10+i;
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

does:

1. (line 1) initialize variable `i` with value 1.
2. (line 2) insert the current value of `i`(=1) to `j`.
3. (line 2) increases `i` from 1 to 2
4. (line 3) compute the result of 10 plus the current value of `i`(=2) (result 12).
5. (line 3) insert result 112 of last computation to `i`.
6. (line 3) print 12

## summery

All of the following codes leave `i` with the same value at the end:

a)

```
int i = 1;
i++;
```

b)

```
int i = 1;
i = i++;
```

c)

```
int i = 1;
int k = i++;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for the answer. In example a output will be 11 please check. you explained very well , but in that example what happened was that we use value of i=1 and add it to 10 then stores into  i itself so answer will be 11 only. i know after that we increment value by one. but we can't use that updated value because we already updated value for i.

Comment: compiler dependent.
here is proof this is working and the output is 12:
https://rextester.com/TNTC21474